# How to handle (failed) validation when creating multiple entities with a REST API

Tags: validation, rest

Let's say I have an endpoint user/1/results and I want to upload multiple results at a time.

So I send it JSON like:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "date": "2014-02-14 03:15:41",
        "score": 18649,
        "time": 42892
    },
    {
        "date": "2013-11-18 09:21:46",
        "score": 7856,
        "time": 23568.8
    }]
}
```

Let's say time needs to be an integer, so the second entity fails validation.

What's the best thing to do:

1. Fail both, nothing saves, respond with error message..
2. Save first entity, respond with error message.

In either case, what would an error message look like? i.e. how/does it specify that it's the second entity that fails validation.

Comment: The trailing comma here makes your json invalid *"time": 42892,*

Answer (score 1):

I think you should fail both and respond with an error message because it might be cumbersome again to track the remaining results.

Error message should give the details of failing location. for example if it fails at the second one then specify it in json response.